# Creacion de nuevo objeto con String desde input

Tags: java, string

La idea es usar un método static para solicitar un String y que el mismo método use ese String como identificador de la variable para la construcción de un nuevo objeto. Lo que quiero es usar lo que el usuario nos envía, como identificador de la variable del objeto en cuestión. Supongo que tengo que asignar ese string a una variable y después usar el literal para construir el objeto y mi pregunta es , cómo usar ese literal sin tener que escribirlo.
Resumiendo: la idea es pedir un nombre, que ese String soliciatdo con scanner sea asignado a una variable tipo String y que después el programa use el literal de esa variable como identificador de la variable de un nuevo iobjeto.

```
public static void getDatos() {


    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);  //creamos flujo de entrada
    System.out.println("Bienvenido. Cuál es su nombre?"); //quiero usar lo que introduzcan
            // como identificador de la variable del siguiente objeto
            nombre=entrada.nextLine();

    Trabajador nombre=new Trabajador(); //donde pone nombre querría usar   
            //el String que acaban de introducir, el literal

     }
```

Comment: No, no se puede. Los nombres de las variables solo existen en tiempo de compilación, en tiempo de ejecución son simplemente direcciones de memoria. Ahora, una solución a tu problema es usar un constructor parametrizado y pasar el nombre del trabajador y listo.

Comment: Por pué el método tiene que static?  Es muy sensilla con objectos no static.

Comment: Static para no tener que crear objeto alguno, sino que se creen en función de si se introducen más datos. La idea es llamar al método, que el método solicite nombre y que con ese String sea creado un objeto cuyo identificador de variable sea ese mismo literal. Seguidamente el programa va solicitando el resto de datos que se asignan a las variables del objeto ya creado y finalmente se procesa todo y se obtiene el resultado que sea. le voy a dar mas vueltas

Comment: Qué más te da como se llame la variable? Eso es irrelevante. Lo que quieres hacer no será crear un objeto `Trabajador` que guarde dentro el nombre que has tecleado en la consola? `Trabajador cualquierNombre= new Trabajador( nombre);` De forma que luego puedas obtener el nombre guardado en el objeto `cualquierNombre`

Comment: No, guardar el nombre lo hago asi:                                                Trabajador t1=new Trabajador(entrada.nextLine()); Ya va el String aquí por parámetro. Creo que como soy novato no hago las preguntas adecuadas. Necesito explorar más Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede, quizas lo mas proximo sea que tengas un metodo que solicite el nombre y que otro metodo se encargue de la creacion de Trabajador, algo asi:

```
public static String obtenerNombre(){
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);  //creamos flujo de entrada

    System.out.println("Bienvenido. Cuál es su nombre?"); 
    //quiero usar lo que introduzcan 
    // como identificador de la variable del siguiente objeto
    nombre=entrada.nextLine();
    return nombre;
}

public static Trabajador crearTrabajador(String nombre){
    return new Trabajador(nombre);
}

public static void main (String [] args){

    String nombre = obtenerNombre();
    Trabajador trabajador = crearTrabajador(nombre);

}

public class Trabajador{

    private String nombre;

    //getter
    //setter

    public Trabajador(){

    }

    public Trabajador(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```